# How do I get all of the application-only or custom roles in an Oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle, authentication, oracle11g

After searching online and reading the Oracle documentation for this, I need some help in getting all of the custom roles found in an Oracle database. Since I can't find a good resource that gives me the logical model of the system tables or data dictionaries (so I could see where the dba_role is mapped to), the best I could come up with was:

```
select role from dba_roles
```

and then from there filter out any sys or sysdba role that I know -- which I know might not be  correct.

Any helpful pointers for which table to use would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the SQL behind the `dba_roles` view:

> select * from dba_views where view_name = 'DBA_ROLES';

Here's the code on my system:

```
select name, decode(password, null,          'NO',
                              'EXTERNAL',    'EXTERNAL',
                              'GLOBAL',      'GLOBAL',
                              'YES'),
             decode(password, null,          'NONE',
                              'EXTERNAL',    'EXTERNAL',
                              'GLOBAL',      'GLOBAL',
                              'APPLICATION', 'APPLICATION',
                              'PASSWORD')
from  user$
where type# = 0 and name not in ('PUBLIC', '_NEXT_USER');
```

When I run `select * from sys.user$ where type# = 0 order by ctime;` I see a lot of views with a `ctime` at about the same time, several years ago.  (The time is even *before* my database was created.)  It's probably safe to assume that the old roles are system generated.

But that does not necessarily mean that the newest roles are all custom roles.  The `ctime` might change after an upgrade or re-compile, or if you install new options.

It may be helpful to install a new instance and subtract whatever you see in that `dba_roles`.

Comment: Thanks. The information on sys.user$ definitely gave me a good lead on the roles. It's not the best solution at the moment, but considering Oracle vastly differs from SQL Server, I had to use an alternate plan of just excluding the known administrative roles we use from the list.